# JBoss 5.1.0 (JSF/Seam) cookies blowing up with accented characters

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, jboss

I cannot see this behavior in JBoss 4.2.3. If I try to call addCookie() on HttpServletResponse and my cookie value has accented characters in it (ex. ç) I get this exception: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value, consider BASE64 encoding your value

Does anyone know what change in JBoss 5.1.0 could be causing these problems?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently they fixed a bug so that the cookie name now finally conforms the [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt).

Also see the [`javax.servlet.http.Cookie` API specification](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#Cookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> The name must conform to RFC 2109. That means it can contain **only ASCII alphanumeric characters** and cannot contain commas, semicolons, or white space or begin with a $ character. The cookie's name cannot be changed after creation.

The c with cedille `ç` is not an [ASCII character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

---

**Update**: sorry, the problem concerns the cookie *value*. This is then related to [this Tomcat bugfix](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44679) (JBoss uses Tomcat under the hoods). This should be workaroundable by setting the cookie version as follows:

```
cookie.setVersion(1);
```

The `ç` is not a valid character for the cookie value according the old Netscape specification, but it is according the newer RFC2109 specification. With the [`Cookie#setVersion()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setVersion%28int%29) you can toggle between them.

Comment: The question asks about cookie values, not the cookie name.

Comment: @Photodeus: I see. I updated the answer. Thank you for retification.

Comment: I've solved the problem by base64 encoding certain cookie values (and decoding when read). I've tried setting the cookie version to 1 but that did not solve the problem. Also, from what I have read, setting cookie version to 1 breaks in IE7. 

Does anyone know what is different in JBoss 5.1.0 because in 4.2.3 I was able to pass values with accents with no problems.